# Can I send a POST/GET Request on an HTML tag in Pug?

Tags: javascript, pug, server-side-rendering

I want to send a GET request on an anchor tag in pug. Is it possible without using form & submit button?

I did this code but it is not executing the server side route, it is directly displaying the page.

```
nav
    ul.pagination
        li.page-item
            a.page-link Prev
        each pageNumber in pages
            li.page-item
                a.page-link(href="/admin?page="+pageNumber)=pageNumber
        li.page-item
            a.page-link Next
```

I want to do something like this:

```
a.page-link(method="GET" action="/admin?page="+pageNumber)=pageNumber
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pug just generates HTML. So start by forgetting about Pug and focus on the HTML  you want to generate.

Links make GET requests. They can't do anything other than make a GET request. They don't accept an `method` attribute.

The URL to make the GET request to is specified by the `href` attribute, not an `action` attribute.

`a.page-link(href="/admin?page="+pageNumber)=pageNumber` already makes the request you appear to want.

It must be executing *some* route on the server, otherwise the server wouldn't respond with a page for the browser to render.